# If a $3\times 3$ matrix satisfies $A^3-A^2-A+I=0$, then it is not necessarily diagonalisable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gre-exam

If a $3\times 3$ matrix satisfies $A^3-A^2-A+I=0$, then it is not necessarily diagonalisable.

I have a counterexample
$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$. But I was hoping for some direct proof. Any hints in this direction would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an example (for your statement that it is **not** diagonalisable), not a counterexample.  A counterexample is a matrix that **is** diagonalisable, e.g. $I$.

Comment: Let $A=I$, then $A$ is diagonalisable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I have edited my question.

Comment: Your edit makes the question more confusing to me.  "Not necessarily diagonalizable" equates to "has no relationship with diagonalization" from what I can see.  Is there any reason to include that portion of the statement?

Comment: @abiessu I mean the given condition need not imply A is diagonalisable.

Comment: @DimensionEntangled:The question is clear now. Any more cleaning will make it unreadable. The only strange part of the question: what do you mean by "direct proof"?

Comment: Your proof (by giving an example) is as direct as can be.

Comment: The matrix above is the classic example of a non-diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: I am just wondering, is this a book question? Because it is worded in a very confusing way...

Comment: One can use any polynomial to locate the set of all possible minimal polynomials for a matrix satisfying that polynomial (if the dimension is given). Then, using the fact that a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots, one sees that there are examples in this case (where the polynomial factors to $(x-1)^2(x+1)$) where $A$ will, and won't, be diagonalizable. Both are possible. This is a method that would avoid construction.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon : surely at some stage one must do a construction to show that both possible minimal polynomials actually occur? [Of course I agree that what you say is exactly how one should think about the question.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician Of course, you're absolutely right. Eventually construction would have to come into play. I'm not sure that you can show the existence of a matrix with a specific minimal polynomial using just abstract methods (although I could be wrong) , so eventually at some point of time you're looking for concrete examples (e.g. using Jordan blocks).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Further thought/retraction - I suppose it is almost obvious that "multiplication by $x$" on $k[x]/(m(x)$ is linear with minimal polynomial $m$ and that would be matrix-free. A bit more bothersome if one want also to get correct dimension and char polynomial, but suitable direct sums will work. Essentially doing the RCF proof backwards.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I think you're correct! It is matrix free and seems to satisfy the conditions. Yes, we may have to do something about the dimension via direct sums, but that's a great start that I didn't actually consider earlier. Thanks for this. You may want to write an answer if you're ready, but we can verify the necessary facts in the comments until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A^3-A^2-A+I=0$ iff
\begin{align}
         0&=(A^3-A)-(A^2-I) \\
          &=A(A^2-I)-(A^2-I) \\
          &=(A-I)^2(A+I).
\end{align}
The minimal polynomial for $A$ could be any one of the following:
$$
          x-1,(x-1)^2,x+1,(x+1)(x-1),(x+1)(x-1)^2.
$$
Recall that $A$ is diagonalizable iff the minimal polynomial for $A$ has no repeated factors. So, there are examples of $A$ that are not diagonalizable, and there are examples that are diagonalizable. Examples of both are easily constructed in Jordan canonical form.